# How to prevent javascript code from executing?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html5-canvas

I ran into a simple and confusing problem:
How do I stop a piece of javascript code from being executed?

In my game, I have a function (with delays, because the function executes a death sequence).
Due to the delays, the function takes 5 seconds to finish execution.

I want this function to fully finish execution before continuing remaining code execution. But the remaining code (which wipes the canvas) gets executed as the function is still executing.

How do I stop this?

Comment: look into using a callback

Comment: Is there a reason the last statement in your death sequence couldn't be calling the function that clears the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Hackish solution:

Have the death sequence set a global variable to `true` when it starts and to `false` when it finish. In the beginning of your render-loop function you check that global variable and `return;` when it's true.

A cleaner solution would be to have proper state-handling in both your logic-loop and render-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your code, but it sounds like you might want to use a callback.

```
function deathSequence(callback) {
    ...
    function step() {
        lots_of_stuff;
        ...
        if(sequence_done) {
            callback();
        } else {
            setTimeout(step, 100);
        }
    }
    step();
    ...
}

function game() {
    ...
    if(dead) {
        deathSequence(function() {
            // Canvas won't get wiped until death
            // sequence is over
            wipe canvas;
        })
    }
    ...
}
```